# How to identify multiple WebElements with multiple criteria in QAF?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, qaf

I'm working on a use case where I need to identify one or more WebElement objects in QAF (Qmetry Automation Framework). In Selenium, I can achieve this by using the @FindAll annotation with multiple @FindBy annotations, like this:

```
@FindAll({
   @FindBy(className = "class1"),
   @FindBy(className = "class2")
})
private List<WebElement> elementsWithEitherClass1OrClass2;
```

However, I couldn't find a similar implementation in QAF. Is there a way to achieve the same result in QAF? I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to approach this in QAF. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QAF supports `FindBy`(org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy), `FindBys`(org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBys) from selenium support library in addition to it's own `FindBy`(com.qmetry.qaf.automation.ui.annotations.FindBy) but not `FindAll`

It doesn't mean you can not use it with QAF. To use `FindAll` you will required to add additional one line code as below in your page class constructor.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory
    ...

class MyPage extends WebDriverBaseTestPage<WebDriverTestPage>

    ...

    public MyPage() {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }
    ...
}
```